# I want to sum column with blanks

Tags: vb.net

I have a column containing amount paid in a sales table.  I want to sum the column and return the result to a textbox but I am having error when the table is empty or when there are Some empty fields in the column.  Please help me out. The error message I get is Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. My code goes thus.

```
Try 
    con.open  
    using command=New OledbCommand("Select SUM(Amt_Paid) From Sales Where Customer = 'Abraham';".con)  
        Dim total = convert.Toint32(Command.ExecutrScalar) 
        Textbox1.Text = total.ToString 
    End Using 
    con.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference: SQL NULL Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Try using one of the suggested SQL NULL function in the provided link

For Example if the connection is to SQL Server then update the query to use `ISNULL` which will return a default value if the field is null.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Amt_Paid, 0)) FROM Sales WHERE Customer = 'Abraham';"
Using command = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim total = convert.Toint32(command.ExecuteScalar) 
    Textbox1.Text = total.ToString 
End Using
```

In the above any time a `Amt_Paid` is null it will default to `0` so that no errors will be encountered when summing up the value.

If using another data store refer to the reference link provided before and see if there is an equivalent version provided.